# Regex patterns doesnt match in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match strings, in a text file. I'm using Python 3.4.3 and regex. I've tested the pattern in regex editor https://regex101.com/r/xZ7iL5/4#python. The Pattern works but when I tested with python It doesn't work: m returns nothing.

### **Boot_info.txt**

---

```
boot.1.type=HARDDISK
boot.1.group=+Hard Drive 
boot.1.name=+ST380215AS
boot.2.type=HARDDISK
boot.2.group=+Hard Drive 
boot.2.name=+ST9250315AS
boot.3.type=USBKEY
boot.3.group=+Unknown Device 
boot.3.name=+U1-KingstonDataTraveler G3 1.00
```

### **CODE**

---

```
Boot_info = "Boot_info.txt"
def Get_boot ():
   global Boot_info 
   Indexes = []
   Names = []
   Types = []
   Form = r"boot(.\d.)type=(.*)\n.*\nboot.\d.name=(.*)"
   with open("Boot_info.txt") as Boot_info:
    p = re.compile(Form) 
    for line in Boot_info:
        m = p.match(line)
        if m != None:
           Index=m.group(1)
           Type=m.group(2)
           Name=m.group(3)
           logging.info("The connected device Index is:%s",Index)
           logging.info("The connected device Type is:%s",Type)
           logging.info("The connected device Name is :%s",Name)
           Indexes.append(Index)
           Types.append(Type)
           Names.append(Name)
           logging.info("The connected devices Types in order are :%s", Types)
           logging.info("The connected devices Names in order are :%s", Names)
        else:
           logging.error("Regex failed!! check the Pattern")
   return (len(Indexes),Types,Names)

import re
L,typ,Nm1=Get_boot()
print('Nm1:',Nm1) 
print('Length:',L)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check (print) the value of `line`, you'll see the problem.

`line` contains one line, and your pattern contains three. `line` will never contain two linebreaks in your example.

You need to rethink the parsing logic, either by manually reading three lines and concatenating them before looking for a match, or by dropping the multi-line regex and writing a parser that recognizes the lines separately.

Comment: by dropping the multiline regex  I can use two forms but I don't no how to do it in a single pattern. Have u any ideas ?

Comment: @MomoEssassi I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "two forms". You can match any of the lines with something like `boot\.(\d+)\.(\w+)=(.*)` and then make decisions based on the value of the 2nd group.

Answer (score 1):

the pattern contains three lines and you just match one line, so m returns nothing.

```
import logging

Boot_info = "Boot_info.txt"


def Get_boot():
    global Boot_info
    Indexes = []
    Names = []
    Types = []
    Form = r"boot(.\d.)type=(.*)\n.*\nboot.\d.name=(.*)"
    with open("Boot_info.txt") as Boot_info:
        p = re.compile(Form)
        for line in Boot_info:
            lines = ""
            lines += line
            lines += Boot_info.readline()
            lines += Boot_info.readline()

            m = p.search(lines)

            if m != None:
                Index = m.group(1)
                Type = m.group(2)
                Name = m.group(3)
                logging.info("The connected device Index is:%s", Index)
                logging.info("The connected device Type is:%s", Type)
                logging.info("The connected device Name is :%s", Name)
                Indexes.append(Index)
                Types.append(Type)
                Names.append(Name)
                logging.info("The connected devices Types in order are :%s", Types)
                logging.info("The connected devices Names in order are :%s", Names)
            else:
                logging.error("Regex failed!! check the Pattern")

    return (len(Indexes), Types, Names)


import re

L, typ, Nm1 = Get_boot()
print('Nm1:', Nm1)
print('Length:', L)
```